# ERROR: Error 1171: All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Usando el espacio de trabajo mysql workbench he creado 4 tablas y un diagrama y quiero que me cree una base de datos utilizando "forward engineer",lo que pasa es que me da el siguiente error:

> Error 1171: All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you
> need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead

Desde mysql model en columns no tengo marcado not null

¿por qué ocurre esto??

Comment: Sería mejor que enseñaras tu diagrama

Comment: Si estas creando un primary key con multiples campos... debes asegurarte de que todos los campos que forman parte del key estan marcados como `NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Las claves primarias no pueden ser nulas, sino, no seria clave primaria, en analogía toda persona debe tener un dni, de lo contrario seria un indocumentado, estaría fuera del sistema. estas creando una primary key con varios campos y uno de ellos lo marcaste como NULL.

Replicando el error:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tabla1`;  
CREATE TABLE `tabla1` (
  `idtabla1` INT NOT NULL,
  `dni` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idtabla1`, `dni`, `name`));
```

resultado :

> *Error Code: 1171. All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead*

corrigiendo:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tabla1`;  
CREATE TABLE `tabla1` (
  `idtabla1` INT NOT NULL,
  `dni` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idtabla1`, `dni`, `name`));
```

Como puedes observar la única diferencia es que el campo dni esta marcado como NOT NULL.